# Azure Automation Account policy for Diagnostic Settings

Tags: azure, resources, policy

I am trying to create an Azure Policy here to audit when diagnostic settings are not set for Automation Accounts.

I cannot find the field to verify if the Automation account saves it.

For now, I noticed this, the settings seem to be here:
Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings

My diagnostic settings are available:
/subscriptions/SUBSCRIPTIONID/resourcegroups/RESOURCEGROUP/providers/microsoft.automation/automationaccounts/AUTOMATIONACC/providers/microsoft.insights/diagnosticSettings/DIAGSETTINGNAME

But how can I use that information in order to have the policy to check if the resource is compliant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the below Policy, here you can pass the Automation accounts (Resource Type) in the parameters. You can find list of built-in policies [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/built-in-policies).

Please follow this [link](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Policy/PolicyDetailBlade/definitionId/%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.Authorization%2FpolicyDefinitions%2F7f89b1eb-583c-429a-8828-af049802c1d9) to view the policy definition on Azure Portal.

```
{
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "Audit diagnostic setting",
    "policyType": "BuiltIn",
    "mode": "All",
    "description": "Audit diagnostic setting for selected resource types",
    "metadata": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "category": "Monitoring"
    },
    "parameters": {
      "listOfResourceTypes": {
        "type": "Array",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Resource Types",
          "strongType": "resourceTypes"
        }
      }
    },
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "field": "type",
        "in": "[parameters('listOfResourceTypes')]"
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "AuditIfNotExists",
        "details": {
          "type": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings",
          "existenceCondition": {
            "allOf": [
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/logs.enabled",
                "equals": "true"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/metrics.enabled",
                "equals": "true"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "id": "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/7f89b1eb-583c-429a-8828-af049802c1d9",
  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
  "name": "7f89b1eb-583c-429a-8828-af049802c1d9"
}
```